# Firebase Cloud Messaging to an individual User

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am struggling to connect the dots on FCM and how I should be approach a problem.

I have an app (Golang if it matters) that runs quite a few async jobs.   When some of them are completed I want to send a notification to an individual user.  I am not connecting from one device to the next, it is initiated by the server and sent directly to the user (web/andoid/ios).

What is the best way to accomplish this?   How do I tell FCM the exact user to send the notification to?   I couldn't find much clarity in the docs.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to get another users uid? Are you storing users info in Firebase Database or Firestore? (uid, name, city, etc)?